# Using Bottle to download file from Azure blob storage

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, bottle

I am using bottle python with azure blob storage:

```
   @route('/download/:filename')
    def getDownload(filename):
      try:
        raw = blob.get_blob('picture', filename)
        return raw
```

Is my code correct to download the file?

**EDIT**

> How did you instantiate the blob, something like: `blob = BlobService(account_name, account_key)`?

```
 blob = BlobService(account_name='xxx', account_key='O6asd7ET+ssadsadNvVLAZ46nB6iHDadavpKbJilKvy0uOJ4/g37923983991djkdjk‌​kajd==')
```

**UPDATE**

This doesn't work:

```
blob = BlobService(account_name='xxx', account_key='O6asd7ET+ssadsadNvVLAZ46nB6iHDadavpKbJilKvy0uOJ4/g37923983991djkdjk‌​kajd==')  

 @route('/download/:filename')
        def getDownload(filename):
          try:
            raw = blob.get_blob('picture', filename)
            return raw
```

This work partially:

```
@route('/download/:filename')
            def getDownload(filename):
              try:
blob = BlobService(account_name='xxx', account_key='O6asd7ET+ssadsadNvVLAZ46nB6iHDadavpKbJilKvy0uOJ4/g37923983991djkdjk‌​kajd==')  
                raw = blob.get_blob('picture', filename)
                return raw
```

Why? and `return raw` gives socket exception.

Comment: Why on Earth don't you try it out before asking?

Comment: I have tested, not working, it just hang.

Comment: how did you instantiate the blob, something like: `blob = BlobService(account_name, account_key)` ?

Comment: blob = BlobService(account_name='xxx', account_key='O6asd7ET+ssadsadNvVLAZ46nB6iHDadavpKbJilKvy0uOJ4/g37923983991djkdjkkajd==')